# Kafka topic compaction does not work. How to debug?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka topic with 240 partitions with clean-up policy as compact and delete retention of 7 days.
With this, I expect the messages to be compacted and be marked for deletion after 7 days.
However, I find an year old messages in the topic and hence I'm sure compaction does not seem to be working.

I would like some guidance on how and where do I look for misconfiguration.
The producer is a SpringKafka Application with Spring v2.7.

I do have broker logs, but I'm not sure what should I look for exactly, there are too many log messages.

Attached a screenshot of the complete configurations.
[image: Topic Configs]

Answer (score 2):

Compaction keeps all uniquely keyed records in a topic, ***forever***.

Perhaps you wanted `cleanup.policy=compact,delete`?

If you're finding duplicate keys from very old log segments, then you can look at the logs for the log cleaner threads, as a start.